# Clear the Multiple Page content in simple coding

Tags: vba

Hi I am having 11 sheets in my workbook. I need to delete some contents in all the sheets except 1 sheet. I have written some code. while I am rund the code activesheet content will be deleted. rest of the contents not deleted. Please help on this. Here is my code

```
Sub ClearData()
Dim sheetsArray As Sheets
    Set sheetsArray = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Qns1", "Qns2", "Qns3", "Qns4", "Qns5", "Adl1", "Adl2", "Adl3", "Adl4", "Adl5"))

    Dim sheetObject As Worksheet

    ' change value of range 'a1' on each sheet from sheetsArray
    For Each sheetObject In sheetsArray
    
    'Do something
        
    Range("B2:C1000,E2:O1000").ClearContents
                
    Next sheetObject
End Sub
```

Comment: `sheetObject.Range("B2:C1000,E2:O1000").ClearContents`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the code is not working...